# I want to get json in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

i want to get json from URL

i try to get json from this URL, but i can't get value from datepicker.
Because i want to use that value to get JSON from URL.

this URL if i open in browser :

http://192.168.11.213:8080/jadwaldokter-v04-0.0.1/Jadwal/JadwalDokterDenganTanggalDokter/2019-01-08/dan/17

this is my blade :

```
//link datepicker
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div>
<input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="dynamics" data-            
dependent="jampraktek"
url="{{url('js/jampraktek.js')}}" width="276" />

<script>
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
format : 'yyyy-mm-dd'
}); 
</script>
</div>
<br>
<div>

<select name="jampraktek" id="jampraktek" class="dynamics" style="width:     
250px;">
<option value=""> Jam Praktek </option>
</select>
{{ csrf_field() }}
</div>
```

this is my route:

```
Route::post('daftarPeriksa/jampraktekterpilih', 
'userController@jampraktekterpilih')- 
>name('usercontroller.jampraktekterpilih');
```

this is my js file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dynamics').change(function(){
if($(this).val() != '')
{
var input = $(this).attr("datepicker");
var value = $(this).val();

var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

$.ajax({
url:'/daftarPeriksa/jampraktekterpilih',
method: "POST",
data:{input:input, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
success:function(result)
{
$('#'+dependent).html(result);
}
})
}
});

$('#datepicker').change(function(){
$('#jampraktek').val('');
});
});
```

this is my controller :

```
function jampraktekterpilih(Request $request){
    $client = new Client();
    $input = $request->get('input');
    $value = $request->get('value');
    $dependent = $request->get('dependent');

    $response = $client->get('http://192.168.11.213:8080/jadwaldokter-v04-0.0.1/Jadwal/JadwalDokterDenganTanggalDokter/'.$value.'/dan/17');
    $res = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    $output = '<option value="">pilih '.ucfirst($dependent).'</option>';
    error_log('message here.');

    foreach($res as $key=>$node)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$this->hari($node->hariPraktek).'">'.$this->hari($node->hariPraktek).'</option>';
    }

    echo $output;
}

public function hari($hari){
    if($hari == 0){
        return "senin";
    } elseif($hari == 1){
        return "selasa";
    } elseif($hari == 2){
        return "rabu";
    } elseif($hari == 3){
        return "kamis";
    } elseif($hari == 4){
        return "jumat";
    } elseif($hari == 5){
        return "sabtu";
    } elseif($hari == 6){
        return "minggu";
    }
}
```

not show anything from my code, i dont know, where is the errors
i new to use laravel

I try to get output like :

[image]

very thankyou if somebody want to help me :))
I will +rep ... :))

Comment: which date picker r u using ? please add link

Comment: okay dude, i add datepicker link

Answer (score 1):

- first you need to import jQuery
- then you need to import datepicker
  JS
- initialize your datepicker inside Jquery's `document.ready()` function
- as you are returning text from your controllers function , so you need to use   `dataType: "text"` in your ajax request

your blade file should be like this :

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="your_datepicker_js_here"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     format : 'yyyy-mm-dd'
   }); 


 $('.dynamics').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
    var input = $(this).attr("datepicker");
    var value = $(this).val();

    var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/daftarPeriksa/jampraktekterpilih',
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "text"
        data: {
            input: input,
            value: value,
            _token: _token,
            dependent: dependent
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $('#' + dependent).html(result);
        },
        error:function(err){
          console.log("Error");
        }
    });
   }
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="dynamics" data-            
dependent="jampraktek" width="276" />
</div>
<br>
<div>
<select name="jampraktek" id="jampraktek" class="dynamics" style="width:     
250px;">
<option value=""> Jam Praktek </option>
</select>
{{ csrf_field() }}
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: okay, i will try. But i already import jQuery and datepicker js, just not showing

Comment: yes i know , you have imported , but im just guideing to do in correct way.

Comment: i got error like this ->>  http://127.0.0.1:8000/daftarPeriksa/jampraktekterpilih 404 (Not Found). but i already import jQuery and other